# Accessing custom script in subdirectory

Tags: magento-1.9

We have a Magento CE 1.9 and we recently purchased a live chat script by the name of phplivesupport.com now we created a new folder called livehelp and uploaded all the script files.

Our issue is anytime we try to access the domain.com/livehelp directory we are just redirected back to the main Magento page. The new directory does not have any `.htaccess` file in it also if we delete all the live chat files and just have a default `index.php` file with the text hello world we then are able to go to the URL domain.com/livehelp and see the hello world text. So there is something with the script causing it to redirect to the main page. even if we in the top line of the scripts `index.php` file we put echo "hello"; die(); and go to the url domain.com/livehtlp still we get rerouted to the Magento main page? Anyone know where to look to fix this?

Comment: Perhaps you have a rule in your main .htaccess which disallows all other subdirectories by executing any php file(s) inside them.

Comment: What happens if you include index.php as part of the url? So target script directly in the call. Possible the index.php is not picked up as the index file.